# Azure Service Bus - Abandoned messages comes back to same subscriber

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using Service Bus queue with 2 subscribers (Trigger based flows - say primary and secondary). Am using peek-lock to receive the message.
If one of the flows decides that this message cant be handled by it, the flow issues an `abandon message in queue` step.
Now with `MaxDeliveryCount` set to 2 in my queue, I would expect the message to be delivered to the next subscriber/flows.

However in my cacse, the issue of the message is completely random. Most of the times the 2nd delivery is issued to the same subscriber (primary). At times the 2nd delivery would go to the backup-flow.

If there a setting to distribute the broadcast uniformly across the subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the desired behavior. There is no distinction between your subscribers/consumers. They compete for messages. If you want to make sure that multiple consumers can receive your message, you should use [topics & subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions). If you only want to process failed messages with a different consumer, you can use the [poison/dead-letter queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions

> If the application is unable to process the message for some reason, it can request the Service Bus service to abandon the message. Service Bus unlocks the message and makes it available to be received again, **either by the same consumer or by another competing consumer.**

(emphasis added)